# Unable to access HBase from MapReduce code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to use HDFS file as source and HBase as sink. My Hadoop cluster has following specification:

```
master 192.168.4.65
slave1 192.168.4.176
slave2 192.168.4.175
slave3 192.168.4.57
slave4 192.168.4.146
```

The Zookeeper nodes are on following ip address:

```
zks1 192.168.4.60
zks2 192.168.4.61
zks3 192.168.4.66
```

The HBase nodes are on following ip addresses:

```
hbmaster 192.168.4.59
rs1 192.168.4.69
rs2 192.168.4.110
rs3 192.168.4.45
```

I have copied the zookeeper-3.4.6.jar to the lib folder of all nodes in Hadoop cluster.
Individually HDFS and HBase work fine. But I'm unable to access HBase using MapReduce.
The driver code for the MapReduce code is:

```
    import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;


public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.addResource("hbase-site.xml");
        //conf.set("hbase.master","hbmaster:60000");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "zks1,zks2,zks3");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");

        try{
            HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
        }
        catch(MasterNotRunningException e){
            System.out.println("Master not running");
            System.exit(1);
        }
         System.out.println("connected to hbase");
        //HTable hTable = new HTable(conf, args[3]);  
        String[] otherArgs=new GenericOptionsParser(conf,args).getRemainingArgs();
        if(otherArgs.length!=2)
        {
            System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job=new Job(conf,"HBase Provenance Component");
        job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class); 
        job.setMapperClass(HBaseMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(HBaseReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        //TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);
        //TableMapReduceUtil.addHBaseDependencyJars(conf);
        System.out.println("Before");
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob("Provenance", HBaseReducer.class, job);

        //job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        //job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        //job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        //job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        System.out.println("After");
        //HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, hTable);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
    }
}
```

The job hangs at this point:

```
   Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 6608@master
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=master
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_79
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/..:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/guava-18.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hbase-0.94.24.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.5.0-60-generic
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hduser
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hduser
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/usr/local/hadoop
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=zks2:2181,zks1:2181,zks3:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zks3/192.168.4.66:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to zks3/192.168.4.66:2181, initiating session
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server zks3/192.168.4.66:2181, sessionid = 0x34d94005a530003, negotiated timeout = 60000
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closed zookeeper sessionid=0x34d94005a530003
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x34d94005a530003 closed
15/05/27 11:46:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
connected to hbase
Before
After
15/05/27 11:46:38 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 6608@master
15/05/27 11:46:38 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=zks2:2181,zks1:2181,zks3:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
15/05/27 11:46:38 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zks2/192.168.4.61:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
15/05/27 11:46:38 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to zks2/192.168.4.61:2181, initiating session
15/05/27 11:46:38 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server zks2/192.168.4.61:2181, sessionid = 0x24d93f965730002, negotiated timeout = 60000
```

Please suggest where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing guave [jar](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Please add it and try running the code. You can also use maven so that once you give basic dependencies, it will fetch all the other dependencies required

Comment: That solved the problem. Now when I start MapReduce job the connection to ZooKeeper is established successfully but the MapReduce job doesn't start. No new statement is printed and the job is not started. Any idea why that could happen?

Comment: Have you tried keeping any sysouts in HBaseMapper class and verified the flow? Or is that mapper class part of Apache Storm framework

Comment: I have tried Sysouts. They all work fine but the job hangs on the last line System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1); The mapper is not part of Apache Storm Framework. I am trying to process a file in HDFS and store output to HBase table. I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1, HBase 0.94.24 and ZooKeeper 3.4.6

Comment: I have updated the current driver code and the current error above in the question please have a look.